# binding to a variable that gets data in async mode in angular 2+

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have the following template that renders user details:

```
<ion-buttons end>
  <button (click)="loadProfilePage()" ion-button clear item-end icon-right>{{ api.userData?.inventory?.points }}/
    <p ion-text color="gold">{{ api.userData?.inventory?.credits }}</p>
    <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

So there is a provider (api) that is fetching this data at the app startup from local storage.

Currently I am using "?" signs to indicate that this evaluation should be "lazy" as data might not be yet there and api.userData can hence return undefined.

Question - is this a proper implementation or should I switch to observable and async pipe?

It feels like what I have right now works, but I am not sure if this approach with ? is exaclty how it should work for data binding to variables who are obtaining their value at the app start form async source (local persistence)

Comment: It depends on how you expect it to behave. Should the button be disabled? Use something like `[disabled]=" api.userData"`, and you should keep `?.`. Should it not exist? Use ngIf, and you can omit `?.`.

Comment: thank you. I did add that and now it feels better (button disabled if data is not yet loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1) You can use the safe navigation operator (?) like you are. That is a valid (and often used) option.

2) Use an ngIf on the button so the button does not even appear until the data is loaded. But that may not meet your requirements.

3) Use a route resolver and preload the data for a route before routing to that component. Then the data is ready for the page before it is displayed and you don't need ngIf or the safe navigation operator.

Comment: ha, pretty clear, in my case seems like its option 1. And probably I need to flag it as disabled as estus suggests!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observable to subscribe when the data was loaded. And is better to use an attribute in the Component, empty by default and bind that attribute. In the subscription you only have to assing the new value.